# Canot get the href value

Tags: javascript

Hi I need to valid the href is empty or not on my page using javascript. I searched the site and found some example, but it didn't worked for me. I must miss something that I didn't notice. Would someone point me the good direction and my mistake. I got the error" Unable to get property 'getattribute' of undefined or null reference. The `<a>` element is like that `<a name="playback" href="">` on html file.

Thanks in advance.

There is my code which is run on load event:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++)
{
     anchors[i].onclick = function() {
         if (anchors == null) {
             alert('null');
         }
         else {
             var link = anchors[i].getAttribute("href");
            //var link= anchors[i].attributes['href']  this line doesn't work too.
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: try to use `this.href;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, the call to `getAttribute` is inside a closure (that is, a function defined "inline" without a name) that is assigned to the onlick event handler of the link. Therefore that code isn't execxuted right away - it doesn't run before the onclick handler triggers.
When the onclick header triggers, two things are passed to the callback function: the element on which the event was triggered is assigned to the `this` variable of the functions context - and the event itself is passed as first parameter. `anchors` however is undefined in the scope of that callback.

So, use either of those:

```
anchors[i].onclick = function () {
    var link = this.getAtrribute("href");
}
```

```
anchors[i].onclick = function (event) {
   var link = event.target.getAttribute("href");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use closure if you want to do it this way since you are using the shared `i` variable which would have been having last value of iteration when your handler runs on click. But since you are looking at that particular anchor, try binding it with bind an event listener and access it using `this.href`:

You can use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener) and for older browser support `attachEvent`

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            var link = this.getAttribute("href");
    })
};
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AFbzD/)**

Or :

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].onclick = getHandler(i);
}

function getHandler(i) {
    return function () { //Now each of your handler has its own `i`
         var link = anchors[i].getAttribute("href");
    }
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bwQV3/)**

Answer (score 1):

You have got a scope problem.
The following code will output **3**:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
}
console.log(i); // 3
```

Similar to the example above your `onclick` is fired **after** the loop is done.
So `i` in your example would equal to `anchors.length`.

And `anchors[anchors.length] === undefined`.

To solve this problem you have to create a new scope.
For example you could use an Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE):

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++)
{
    (function(j){
       anchors[j].onclick = function() {
         if (anchors == null) {
             alert('null');
         }
         else {
             var link = anchors[j].getAttribute("href");
             }
        }
      }
    }(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen getAttribute before so I performed some tests on it. It turns out that `href` and `getAttribute("href")` are quite different. Namely `href` is the absolute url and `getAttribute("href")` is the relative url to the page. See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4WhYS/).

The problem with your code is that the var is captured in the closure of onclick and when the onclick function runs the value will of `i` will be `anchors.length`.

**Solution, Scratch that use the code from `Johannes H.` His is better**

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
  (function () {
    var current = anchors[i]; //Capture the anchor element
    current.onclick = function() {
     var link = current.getAttribute("href");
    };
  } ());
}
```

Comment: You are still using `i` inside the onclick handler.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to change that my bad.

Comment: No you are totally right i forgot to change `anchors[i]` to `current` on the line `var link = current.getAttribute("href");` http://jsfiddle.net/N72Ug/1/

Answer (score -2):

See this w3 schools page for how to get the href attribute from anchor tags.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_anchor_href.asp

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++)
 {
     anchors[i].onclick = function() {
         if (anchors == null) {
             alert('null');
         }
         else {
             var link = this.href;

             }
       }
}
```

Comment: w3schools is not really a suitable reference - it'S like linking wikipedia in scientific work. Despite the name, w3schools has nothing to do with the W3C. You might want to use MSDN as reference when posting API info.

Comment: MSDN is specific to Microsoft is it not? So posting MSDN is saying if you were using IE this is how you would do it. W3Schools is a very reputable source, all be-it not W3C it is accurate.

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be "MDN" - the mozilla development network. While that one is specific to mozilla, they usually cover other browsers.

Comment: This is effectively what I was going to answer. Not sure why it was downvoted

Comment: Doesn't really matter if W3schools is correct or not the fact is this answer does not solve the problem in OPs question.